# PInvoke from windows service

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I am trying to call a cpp dll function from a c# windows service but every time it makes the call - the service immediately stops and does not display any errors or throw exceptions and the event logs are empty. I have also tried making the PInvoke call thru another assembly (outside the service) and it works. The service is being compiled in x86 (same as the assembly).

Any ideas?

Below is my code:

```
[DllImport(@"C:\Test.dll",
            EntryPoint = @"TestFn",
            SetLastError = true,
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern int TestCppDll();
```

to invoke im simply calling `TestCppDll();`

This fixed my issue:

I changed the TestFn fn in the cpp code from

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int
    TestFn() 
{
      return 1;
}
```

To:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall 
    TestFn() 
{
      return 1;
}
```

Then I changed the c# calling convention to use std instead of Cdecl

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the service?

Comment: I'd guess that the DLL load fails in the context of the service user. What user are you running the service under? I hope you aren't using LOCALSYSTEM! As an aside, you should not be doing `SetLastError = true` I'd guess. That's just for Windows API functions.

Comment: @ConradFrix yes I did try stepping through the service. As soon as TestCppDll(); is called, the service just stops.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am using localsystem. Is that incorrect for PInvoke calls? Thanks for the tip on the SetLastError, removed it. :)

Comment: LOCALSYSTEM is wrong full stop. Don't do it! Try getting the server to log on as a real user, for example you. I'm not saying that's the long term solution, but it might lead us in the right direction. Could you also show us what `TestCppDll/TestFn` looks like.

Comment: Hi Bryan, is there a generic exception handler surrounding the TestCppDll function call? The reason I ask for this is that an account permission problem should rise a managed exception, but if the process is dying without raising an exception, then I would suspect something inside the unamanged code in the DLL, but then again, it should fail in your non-service test case...

Comment: I ended up fixing the problem. I changed the cpp fn to have __stdcall on the extern modifier then called it in c# with the std calling convention. I dont know why that fixed it, but it did.. All is working now, thanks for all the help everyone!

Comment: @sgorozco yea I after I changed the cpp code to use std it worked.. I think you were on to something with it throwing an exception that just wasnt getting back to the c# service. Thanks for the suggestion!